# database cluster fail over

Tags: cluster-computing, failover

I planed to develop a HA program for MSSQL, but I got a question when reading some articles about cluster.

When master is down, then slaves vote for a new master, and the new master will take over virtual IP address of the old one.

What is virtual IP address here ?

For example:

A: master 192.168.1.100 
B: slave  192.168.1.101 
C: slave  192.168.1.102

Is there a another IP address assigned to A? or the IP 192.168.1.100 is the virtual IP ?

If an additional IP need to be assigned to master, what the kind of IP it is? public or local, and how it is assigned to server in C# code.

Windows system.

It is not possible to add extra network cards.

Thanks.

:D

Comment: Off-topic here, probably on-topic at http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but I am sure it's not about database, like server architecture more.

Answer (score 0):

In the MSSQL, every instance has an endpoint. In your case, each IP address should be the instance IP addresses. 
When the master is down, no IP address should be resigned. It keeps as is. 
During failover, Windows Failover Cluster will tell Secondary B or C which is voted to be new Primary.

When you create an Availability Group, you can create an AG listener for your HA. Usually this listener is the interface that client access to. By SQL Server, HA will route your traffic to the current primary.

```
Client -> AG endpoint (public IP / Private IP) -> Primary (192.168.1.100)
                                               -> Secondary (192.168.1.101)
                                               -> Secondary (192.168.1.102)
```

After Failover, Client still access same IP address, which is the AG listener.

```
Client -> AG endpoint (public IP / Private IP) -> Secondary (192.168.1.100)
                                               -> Primary   (192.168.1.100)
                                               -> Secondary (192.168.1.102)
```

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213080.aspx